# How to set the test attribute in <s:if> to a boolean function in action class

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am deciding whether to show a div on a jsp page or not based on the value returned by a boolean function.

```
<s:if test="<s:property value="hasSpecs()"/>" >
//Inside divs
</s:if>
```

The error I am getting is

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /viewer.jsp (line: 99, column: 41) equal symbol expected
```

and it points to the above  line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't nest tags inside other tags' attributes; think of JSP as XML in this regard. It doesn't even really make sense, since the `test` attribute is an OGNL expression, just like the `value` expression in the property tag. It looks like this should be a property, though, e.g., `showSpecs` would be a boolean property implemented by `isShowSpecs` or `getShowSpecs` in the action.

Comment: @DaveNewton The question though is about using a function, not a property. Because OP has a C/C++ background you should apologize the term of function has not equivalent in Java, and closer equivalent is a method.

Comment: @RomanC There aren't any parameters, a property  (which is a method, after all) is cleaner. YMMV.

Comment: @DaveNewton It might be cleaner YMMV, but OP asked about *function in action class* and the name of the function is `hasSpecs`. Should he ask a different question to me more clear?

Comment: @RomanC No, we should be responsible, and provide *additional information* that indicates what best practices are. Leaving a comment regarding alternatives is the correct approach, which is what I did. Please note the language I used in my comment (not an answer, a *comment*): "It **looks** like this should be a property". I used that language because it **looks** like this should be a property, because there's no reason to have it be a method. You answered the question, I provided additional information, and even with your love of fighting over trivial matters, this one eludes me.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes you said "looks like" on your comment, but it absolutely doesn't look like the OP is asked. I didn't like to fight on it, but I noted that your information could be helpful in general but *not in this case* until OP confirm that he thought about property, not a function. Because it's a different thing and conceptually wrong if you follow  the JavaBeans convention.  Please call things by the name, don't call a white to black and otherwise.  And I just dropped  a note that your comment is obsolete, I didn't like to fight with you. But you are fighting with me, what's up?

Comment: @RomanC It's absolutely *not* wrong if you follow the JavaBeans conventions; boolean properties should be exposed as such. There's no reason to use method notation when it's a boolean. When it's not clear the OP knows the options it's our responsibility to inform and educate, and the OP seemed satisfied with what was said.

Comment: @DaveNewton I didn't say that following JavaBeans conventions is wrong, but the question OP has asked "How to set the test attribute in <s:if> to a boolean **function** in action class". OGNL has support for a function call using `e.method(args)` notation, where `e` is a `top` object, method `hasSpecs`, and documentation omitted that fact that null-arg methods is accepted reinterpreting that `null` arguments  lead to unexpected results. But these are different things, the property using another notation `e.property`. A getter needed, why OP should use another method instead of one is posted?

Comment: I suggested renaming to follow JavaBean conventions. These conventions should be preferred. There's no extra work, there's no need for the parentheses, meaning is preserved. Your objection is pointless: I suggested a different approach that maintains compatibility across both S2 and Java conventions in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Struts tags inside the tag's attribute. You can use OGNL expression in the `test` attribute to call the `boolean` method.

```
<s:if test="hasSpecs()">
//Inside divs
</s:if>
```

Comment: Thank you. So I gather I can directly call the method defined in my struts action

Comment: yes, OGNL allows it to call a method from the view layer.